# Debug C++ code in visual studio from python code running in eclipse

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio, eclipse

Does any one know how we can do this?
I have python code in eclipse and whenever it calls c++ functions, i want the break point to go to the visual studio c++ project.

Comment: What are the link between your two pieces of code ? Can you use the Visual Studio debugger with your Python app ?

Comment: Have you tried `Debug -> Attach to Process` from Visual Studio?

Comment: debug->attach to process is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `__debugbreak` in visual studio so that every time the code is invoked it triggers the debugger (you may want to search the function in MSDN).

Insert the instruction in the C++ function (or class method) you want to debug, e.g.

```
void foo()
{
  __debugbreak();
  [...]
}
```

at this point compile the library and run the python script, when library loads and the code is executed a messagebox appears telling if you want to attach the visual studio debugger.

It is the replacement of the old `__asm { int 3 }`.

Answer (score 2):

If the C++ app runs as a separate process then its pretty easy. You can run the process yourself or attach visual studio to existing running process and put break points.

If C++ code  is an embedded DLL/LIB then you can use python as debug/launch process. As soon as python will load the DLL/LIB into your python code visual studio will activate your break points.

Alternatively you can also add windows debugger launcher calls to your code. As soon as your code gets executed, you will see a dialog box asking if you want to attach a debugger.