# Debug C++ code running from python script in Eclipse

Tags: python, c++, eclipse, debugging

I have a C++ project and a python script that calls .exe file. I set breakpoints in one of cpp files, but they are not hit. I can't even go into this C++ project. 
I found similar question here, but for Visual Studio:
[Debug C++ code in visual studio from python code running in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351110/debug-c-code-in-visual-studio-from-python-code-running-in-eclipse)

Is there a similar way to do this trick in Eclipse?
Or is there some other approriate way to debug C++ code, which is called from another process? I tried to attach to the process, but the problem is that, after script makes call, child process finishes very fast and I can't catch its pid.

Comment: Are you trying to debug input passed into the executable from the script?

Comment: Inter-process debugging is more art than science. Try adding a prompt right at the begining of main to give yourself some time.

Answer (score 0):

To debug the executable, use the [DebugBreak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in place of a breakpoint in your program.  So in your C++ code, call `DebugBreak` somewhere in your program, preferably near the beginning -- this will serve as the breakpoint.

What will happen is that when your C++ executable runs from Python, your C++ executable will "crash" (not really crash, but it will seem like it did).  What really is happening is that the `DebugBreak` function was called.

After the Windows OS goes through its set of message boxes saying "your application has something wrong with it" (note that there really is nothing wrong with the program), you are then given the option to debug it.  Choose the "debug" option, the debugger you want to use (which will be Visual Studio), and you should be able from that point on to single step through your C++ code.

Comment: Since I use Ubuntu, I tried its linux analogue `__builtin_trap()`. However, breakpoint is not hit and program now crashes, returning "non-zero exit status -4"